# Angular 2+/NodeJS/Express: Routing fails on page refresh

Tags: node.js, angular, express, heroku, routes

So I thought this was a Heroku problem first, but the same thing happens when running locally with NodeJS.

The homepage of my Angular app displays fine, and the routes work properly when navigating using the links.

BUT, if I try to refresh the page on a route (let's say /login), then the server responds with just this text:
`/app/dist/meal-planner/index.html` on Heroku, and
`/Users/name-here/Development/workspace/meal-planner/dist/meal-planner/index.html` locally

Here is my **server.js:**

```
//Install express server
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

// Serve only the static files form the dist directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/meal-planner')));

// For all GET requests, send back index.html (PathLocationStrategy)
app.get('*', (req,res) => {
    res.send(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/meal-planner/index.html'));
});

// Start the app by listening on the default Heroku port
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.set('port', port);
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port, () => console.log('Running on port ' + port));
```

And my [folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K24u.png) just in case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
res.send(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/meal-planner/index.html'));
```

`path.join` returns a string and you're sending that string as a response. This explains why the server responds with text.

You probably want [`sendFile`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile) instead of `send`:

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/meal-planner/index.html'));
```